# Create dynamic stored function through java

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, stored-functions

```
Stored function is as fallows 

Stored Function 

DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getPKColumns` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getPKColumns`(
  world VARCHAR(64),
  countrylanguage VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  DECLARE PKColumns TEXT;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR '`, `')
  FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
  WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = world)
    AND (`TABLE_NAME` = countrylanguage)
    AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')
    INTO PKColumns;
  SET PKColumns = CONCAT('`', PKColumns, '`');
  RETURN PKColumns;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I wanted it to convert into Java , so I can execute it with Statement(java.sql). When I am writing it as same in execute like statement.execute(sql) its giving me syntax error.
please help me how to convert the above mention stored function to its java equivalent.
Thankx..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "convert [it] into Java , so I can execute it with Statement(java.sql)". Do you want to use Java code to *create* the Function in the MySQL database? (It is MySQL, right? If so, please add the [mysql] tag.) Or, do you want to create a Java method to *replicate* the Function by executing the same SQL statement and returning the results as a String?

Comment: Yes I want java code to create this function.Like we use to create Table through java code